# Show that $x' = Ax$ is an attractor if end only if there is a quadratic form $q$ positive definite such that $Dq(x) . Ax < 0$ for all $x \neq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponentiation, exponential-function

Show that $x' = Ax$ is an attractor if end only if there is a quadratic form $q$ positive definite such that $$Dq(x) . Ax < 0$$ for all $x \neq 0$

**Definition:** a linear system $x' = Ax$ called attractor if for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ called $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  e^{tA} = 0$$